# C Linux. Два процесса из одного родительского

Tags: c, linux

Может ли кто-нибудь описать механизм создания из одного родительского процесса двух других? Я пробовал примерно так:

```
if((one /*первый потомок*/ = fork()) != 0)    
{ 
   if((two /*второй*/ = fork()) != 0)
     ...   // также родительский
   else 
     ...   // второй потомок
}
else {
   ...     //действия первого потомка
}
```

Проверки на ошибку fork() в настоящем коде есть. В нем вообще происходит передача строк из потомков к родителю. Со второго потомка все передается, но с первого - нет. Хотя думаю, конструкция сама по себе неправильная.

---

Вот код программы (исправленный вариант, но не верно работающий):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define READ 0
#define WRITE 1
#define SIZE 1024

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pid_t pid1, pid2;
    int fd[2], fdNew[2];
    char* str[2];

    if(pipe(fd) == -1)
    {
        perror("Pipes!");
        exit(0);
    }

    if((pid1 = fork()) < 0)
    {
        perror("First!");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(pid1 != 0)       //родительский процесс!!!
    {
        close(fd[WRITE]);
        read(fd[READ], str[0], SIZE);
        close(fd[READ]);
        printf("%s\n", str[0]);

        if(pipe(fdNew) == -1)
            perror("Second pipe!");

        if((pid2 = fork()) < 0)
        {
            perror("Sec!");
            exit(2);
        }

        if(pid2 != 0)
        {
            close(fdNew[WRITE]);
            read(fdNew[READ], str[1], SIZE);
            close(fdNew[READ]);
            printf("%s\n", str[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            close(fdNew[READ]);
            str[1] = " world!";
            write(fdNew[WRITE], str[1], strlen(str[1]) + 1);
            close(fdNew[WRITE]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        close(fd[READ]);
        str[0] = "WELL WELL WELL";
        write(fd[WRITE], str[0], strlen(str[0]) + 1);
        close(fd[WRITE]);
    }
}
```

Программа по идее должна вывести "WELL WELL WELL world!". Но надпись выводится так 4 раза, при этом первые два раза str[0] инициализирован (т.е. в ней хранится "Well well well"), а остальные два раза выводятся крякозябры.

Comment: Я не вижу здесь создания _двух_ дочерних процессов. Вы случайно ещё один вызов `fork()` не пропустили? Или я не так понял ваш вопрос, и под созданием двух процессов вы подразумеваете разделение исходно процесса на два после вызова `fork()`? Уточните, пожалуйста, что именно вы пытаетесь сделать.

Comment: Исправил. Нет, в итоге должно получиться три процесса: один родительский и два дочерних (от него же).

Comment: Ок, вижу. А что вы подразумеваете под фразой "передача строк _из потомков к родителю_"? Может, наоборот? Или код, относящийся к передаче данных вы тоже опустили?

Comment: @fori1ton , да, опустил. Операции read/write с предварительным pipe() для двух массивов (для связки "родитель<->потомок_1" и "родитель<->потомок2"). И да, строки передаются из потомка к родителю. Вообще как раз с передачей данных проблем нет, разве что от первого процесса строка не передается. Хотя, кажется, я придумал, что делать.

Comment: Странный вы человек. Вы хотите, чтобы вам помогли, но не желаете опубликовать код, вызывающий проблему. Хотя бы решение ваше опубликуйте, если оно вам поможет. Или код, если не поможет.

Comment: Ну раз код так нужен...

Comment: Думаю, что с запуском процессов всё в порядке, а проблема с pipe'ами. Чтобы проверить, правильно ли запускаются процессы, уберите передачу данных, и пусть запущенный процесс печатает на консоль свой process id.

Comment: @VladD, да, родитель у потомков одинаковый, видимо, действительно c pipe'ами что-то не то.

Comment: @master_clown: Кстати! Вы ведь запускаете на самом деле **три** процесса, правильно? Первый потомок тоже делает `fork`.

Comment: @VladD, вызовов форка два, процессов три: один родительский и два потомка. Или вы имеете в виду четыре процесса, с родительским если учитывать?

Comment: @master_clown: Угу, со стартовым. Смотрите, сначала есть стартовый процесс, он порождает потомка №1. Потом они оба порождают по потомку, №2 и №3. Всего 4 процесса.

Comment: @VladD, я ужасно спать хочу, так что могу ошибиться: первый раз форк запускается в общей программе, деля ее на два процесса, второй же запускается в части основного процесса, поэтому родителем нового процесса является основной процесс. Во всяком случае, этого я пытался добиться. В любом случае, сейчас главное - это передать строку символов из потомков 1 и 2 родителю. И туту я не знаю, то ли два раза pipe вызывать, то ли один раз...

Comment: @master_clown: не-не, у вас второй fork вызывается безусловно, как в основном процессе, так и в первом потомке. Я имею в виду второй кусок кода (под текстом «Вот код программы»), а не первый, в первом всё в порядке с этим.

Comment: @master_clown: Возможно, лучше просто посмотреть на код утром, станет самоочевидно (из личной практики)

Comment: @VladD, увы, сдавать скоро нужно. Но как тогда создать двух потомков от одного родителя?

Comment: @master_clown: Ну, так же, как у вас в _первом_ куске кода. Там второй fork находится внутри `if`'а, и поэтому вызывается только в родителе.

Comment: @VladD, заменил. Все равно строка из внутреннего потомка пропадает

Comment: @master_clown: Хорошо, добавьте новый код тогда в вопрос.

Comment: @VladD, уже заменил, сделан он по образцу первого куска

Comment: @VladD, эмм, забавно, но программа сработала, когда я заменил массив строк на два отдельных массива символов. Т.е. char* str[2] на char one[SIZE] и char two[SIZE]. Все передалось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В принципе идеи правильные, но как-то все запутано.

IMHO такой порядок действий проще и понятней. Ненужное (в данном случае) освобождение ресурсов и детальные проверки я для краткости опустил.

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ cat c.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <sysexits.h>

#define WWW "Well Well Well "
#define World "World!"

int 
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  pid_t p1, p2;
  int fd1[2], fd2[2];

  if (pipe(fd1) || pipe(fd2))
    err(EX_OSERR, "pipe");

  // Запустим 2-х потомков
  if ((p1 = fork()) == 0) { // Первый
    write(fd1[1], WWW, sizeof(WWW) - 1);
    exit(0);
  }
  if (p1 > 0 && (p2 = fork()) == 0) { // Второй
    write(fd2[1], World, sizeof(World) - 1);
    exit(0);
  }
  if (p1 < 0 || p2 < 0)
    err(EX_OSERR, "fork");

  // Прочтем их вывод
  char buf[sizeof(WWW) + sizeof(World)];
  int l, l1;
  if ((l = read(fd1[0], buf, sizeof(WWW))) < 0 ||
      (l1 = read(fd2[0], buf + l, sizeof(World))) < 0)
    err(EX_SOFTWARE, "read pipes");
  buf[l + l1] = 0;

  return puts(buf) == EOF;
}
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ gcc c.c ; ./a.out; echo $?
Well Well Well World!
0
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

Вообще говоря, надо бы добавить пару `wait()` для получения статуса завершения потомков, но это уж в следующий раз (а может автор вопроса и сам в этом разберется).

**Update**

О wait(). Эта функция (на самом деле частный случай waitpid() (см. `man waitpid`)) ожидает завершения любого из потомков и позволяет определить причину его завершения.

Добавим к примеру несколько строк перед main

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>  // это просто для разнообразия в примере (увидите ниже)

void 
pri_status (const char *msg, pid_t p, int status)
{
  printf("Process %ld [%s] ", (long)p, msg);
  if (WIFEXITED(status))
    printf("exited with code %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
  else if (WIFSIGNALED(status))
    printf("terminated by signal %d\n", WTERMSIG(status));
  else if (WIFSTOPPED(status))
    printf("stoped by signal %d\n", WSTOPSIG(status));
  else
    puts("continued...");
}
```

и после чтения данных от потомков

```
  // Получим статус завершения потомков
  int status;
  pid_t p;

  printf("Wait for %ld & %ld\n", (long)p1, (long)p2);
  while ((p = wait(&status)) != -1)
    if (p == p1 || p == p2)
      pri_status(p == p1 ? "First" : "Second", 
                 p, status);
    else 
      pri_status("Unknown", p, status);

  //  wait(0); вернется сразу, если потомков больше нет с errno == ECHILD
  perror("wait");
```

(кстати, в нашем случае можно разместить этот код и сразу после запуска потомков, перед чтением их вывода. (Ничего не изменится))

И немного разнообразим поведение запущенных процессов. Завершим первый

```
    exit(time(0) % 2);
```

а второй

```
    abort();
```

вместо однообразных `exit(0)`.

Оттранслируем gcc c.c (любителям можно g++, тут без разницы) и запустим ./a.out

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./a.out 
Wait for 4871 & 4872
Process 4871 [First] exited with code 1
Process 4872 [Second] terminated by signal 6
wait: No child processes
Well Well Well World!
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ echo $?
0
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

Надеюсь, теперь все немного прояснилось.

Замечу, что если вы обрабатываете сигналы, то возможна ситуация, когда вызов `wait` завершается возвратом -1, но не все процессы завершились. Это произойдет, если вызов был прерван сигналом и в sigaction не задан `SA_RESTART`. В таком случае нужно проверять переменную errno на равенство EINTR.

Для лучшего понимания можно почитать немного man-ов (fork, clone, exit, execl, wait, signal... и по SEE ALSO в них) и не бояться экспериментов с обильной печатью.

Comment: Да, в принципе, разобрался, см. последний коммент выше. Кстати, был бы отдельно благодарен, если бы описали, для чего нужна функция wait()?

Comment: @master_clown, добавил в **Update**